# Can't show image display windows in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, window

I am using openCV python bindings. I am trying to show the output image using the following listing:

```
cv.NamedWindow('display')
cv.MoveWindow('display', 10, 10)
cv.ShowImage('display', cvImage)
```

But I do not see any window.

My platform is Linux (openSuse 11.4), python-opencv version 2.1 and python 2.7.

Comment: On a side note, you might consider PyOpenCV, it's a somewhat worthier Python binding.

Comment: @susmits thanks :) However its not available with distro repos. Installation from source only.

Comment: This problem appears in Linux, but not in Windows systems (at least not in Win 7). In Windows 7 `cv.NamedWindow('...')` immediately displays window, even without `cv.WaitKey()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call the WaitKey function to process the events. Check out the documentation: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_user_interface.html#waitkey

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing, unless HighGUI is used within some environment that takes care of event processing.

Just add a WaitKey(0) at the end of your code and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks that worked :) Now I face another problem I can't kill the window without killing it. DestroyWindow() doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll need to pump events once you've destroyed a window. Immediately after a call to DestroyWindow('display'), add WaitKey(1). That'll cause it to wait for a millisecond, which is unnoticeable enough, and get rid of the window.

Comment: That worked, thanks :) I would point out that openCV's gui functionality is not so good. Often its better to save image to a temporary file and open the image in external viewer.

Comment: Oh, absolutely! The big caveat with WaitKey is that it doesn't reliably pump events unless a window has focus, so if you want to tether the console and the GUI together in some application, be prepared for some annoyances :)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to this information: WaitKey(1) does not wait for 1ms but for at least 15ms...you can measure that if you want.

Comment: Specifically, this would depend from platform to platform. On Windows, for instance, it is not possible to wait for less than the time that it takes to perform one pump of the message loop.